# Change an input field's value while it has onkeypress proprety set to return false

Tags: python, selenium

I'm using selenium in order to access a page that has 2 input fields that I would like to modify. The thing is that `send_keys()` won't work since they have their "onkeypress" proprety set to return false, for example:

```
<input name="ctl00$MainContent$tbFromDate" type="text" value="01/08/2014" 
id="ctl00_MainContent_tbFromDate" onkeypress="return false;"
calendar="ctl00_MainContent_popCalendartbFromDate" format="dd/mm/yyyy" dir="rtl" autocomplete="off" 
onfocus="__PopCalSetFocus(this, event);">
```

I'm successfully finding them with `find_element()` and clearing their default value with `clear()`, but as I mentioned `send_keys()` won't work.

Is there another way to change their value?

Thanks.